# Converting a text XHR-Response to arraybuffer

Tags: javascript, html, image, xmlhttprequest

I'm making an XHR request. At the time of making the request, I don't know whether the URL will return an image or not, so I'm setting `xhr.responseType="text"`

If the response returns with a Content-Type of image/png [or any other image MIME type], I'm making another request with `xhr.responseType="arraybuffer"`. I then use the arraybuffer that's returned to render the image:

```
var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
var i = uInt8Array.length;
var binaryString = new Array(i);
while (i--) {
    binaryString[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);
}
var data = binaryString.join('');
var base64 = window.btoa(data);
//use this base64 string to render the image
```

Is there any way I can avoid making the second request?

I tried doing this -

```
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(responseText.length);
var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);

for (var i=0, i<responseText.length; i++) {
    bufView[i] = responseText.charCodeAt(i);
}

return buf;
```

but the `responseText` isn't the same as the `data` in the first code sample, and the resultant ArrayBuffer doesn't render the image correctly.

Comment: Why would you do another request? If you change the `responseType`, the value of `response` should be recalculated accordingly, and there is no need to ever set it to "text" because the text representation is always available in the `responseText` property.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The headers are available when the readyState is 2, and I can do the transformation then.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a PDF being corrupted, but the handler is generic and handles text, JSON and files.

The easiest way to solve this is to do it the other way round: Always make the request with:

```
xhr.responseType = "blob";
```

Then when you want the response as text, just convert the binary data to text:

```
xhr.response.text().then(text => {
    // do something
});
```

Having binary as the default return type I can just convert that to text where needed.